# Stop SQL Tracing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

my MSSQL DB creates every second two SQL Server Profil - tace data file:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I stop that, because we don't want to tracing something and it files my memory?

My `SELECT * FROM sys.traces` is empty.
If I execute `SELECT * FROM sys.server_event_sessions`, the result looks like the following Screenshot:

[image]

Additionally, I execute the following command:

```sql
SELECT s.name, CAST(st.target_data AS XML).value('(/EventFileTarget/File/@name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions s
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets st ON s.address = st.event_session_address  
WHERE target_name = 'event_file
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Next, I open the *system_health*-file and get this displayed:
[image]

The *hkenginexesession*-file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough permission to see trace list?

The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securable that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission. For more information, see [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16).

If the list is still empty with sysadmin premission then check if these files are created by Extended events:

USING SSMS:

> Server > Management > Session

USING TSQL

```
SELECT s.name, CAST(st.target_data AS X`enter code here`ML).value('(/EventFileTarget/File/@name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions s
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets st ON s.address = st.event_session_address  
WHERE target_name = 'event_file'
```

The above query return session name and filename of outputs.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. I execute the above command as sa-user. As sa I have to see everything, right?

Comment: Yes, I think. @Christian29

Comment: If I execute the above command as sa, the return is an empty table.

Comment: Perhaps the files are created by Extended Events. Did you check that? @Christian29

Comment: No, how can I check that?

Comment: @Christian29 see my answer updates.

Comment: I delete"enter code here" in  ```st.target_data AS X`enter code here`ML``` to execute the above command. Is it right?